# meanings of elements in args list used in subprocess.call()

Tags: python, subprocess

```py
subprocess.call([Exepath, '/cc', installerfile])
```

What does the `'/cc'` do.

I have seen a wide range of 'argument' specification styles for subprocess.call()- some for  shell, command line purposes etc. so as a beginner I am quite confused. What determines what is used in the argument list and what does that '/cc' do in the example up here? what are the other variants for passing arguments to that method and the justification for each variant?
In essence, start from the very beginning of the subprocess topic :)

Comment: What `/cc` does depends on what `Exepath` is

Comment: The meaning or effect of `/cc` is defined by the program named in `Exepath`. Without knowing what that is, we have no way to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The first element of the list is a command and the other elements are its arguments. Without knowing the value of `Exepath`, all we can tell you is that it apparently accepts `/cc` as an argument; perhaps the surrounding code can provide hints as to which command's documentation to read (for example, if `Exepath` is `vc++`, read the documentation for that to see whether it has an option with this name, and if so, what it does).

Comment: OK folks, Interestingly the 'EXEpath is the not a command but the full path to the ' compiler32'  executable for the inno setup 5 compiler program. - precisely 'C:\program Files\Inno Setup 5\Compiler32'. The Installer file is also the full path to the installer .iss file that the Inno setup program needs to run to produce some output installer  .exe file whose name is predefined in the custom  iss installer file. So now I hope you appreciate why this is all strange to me as it is not like what I see in typical documentation saying the first one is a command etc. i need to know what '/cc' does

Comment: If it doesn't have any documentation, maybe try `Compiler32 /?` (with the full path to the executable if it's not on your `PATH`, obviously) to hopefully see a summary of its options. If it's just an internal component of an installer, it's not entirely unlikely that it's simply undocumented, though. Perhaps the option letters can suggest some semantic meaning if you know the domain of the tool ("C compiler"? "Carbon copy"? "Chicken curry"?)